# Alter Table with AWS Aurora Cluster with large table(700GB)

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a very large table (700GB) in Aurora Database Cluster. When I run ALTER command to add new fields, it shows error 'Table is Full'. This is due to filling up the temporary space on the instance, which is sized according to the host instance size we select.

In my case free local storage is around 300 GB for (db r5 large). What is the alternate way of adding field to the table. I am thinking of Adding a new table with updated field and then copying the data from original table.